# How do you get the message from PlatformException?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I made a https call in cloud functions and threw an error if a condition fails, in flutter i handled it successfully and it shows me this : PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: FAILED_PRECONDITION, details: null, message: Error: Your card was declined.})

but i want to know how i can get just the message part to display to the user? so far i already tried e.message but that didnt work

```
CloudFunctions(app: Firebase.app(), region: 'asia-southeast2')
      .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'addPayment')
      .call({
    'paymentMethodId': paymentMethod.id,
    'userid': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
  }).catchError((e) => print('ERROR $e'));
```

this is my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PlatformException class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PlatformException-class.html) has the following properties:

- `code` → String An error code. final
- `details` → dynamic Error details, possibly null. final
- `hashCode` → int The hash code for this object. [...] read-only,
  inherited
- `message` → String **A human-readable error message**, possibly null.
  final
- `runtimeType` → Type A representation of the runtime type of the
  object. read-only, inherited

To [handle it](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#handling-specific-errors) you would do:

```dart
.catchError((e) {
    if (e is PlatformException){
         // Show e.details['message']
    }else{
         print('ERROR $e');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.catchError((error) {
  String errorMessage = error.toString();
  if (error is PlatformException &&
      error.message != null &&
      error.message!.isNotEmpty) {
    errorMessage = error.message!;
  }
}
```